# Deployment is placing an ssh key for a github contributor in its own work directory. How can I make the key available for github pull?

Tags: ssh

given the key and a configuration:

*work/.ssh/githubcontributor_rsa*

```
<private key>
```

*work/.ssh/config*

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    User iamcontributor
    Port 443
    IdentityFile ./githubcontributor_rsa
```

What is necessary to do so that the above key is found?

I already tried to place a symbolic link in ~/.ssh targeting work/.ssh

Comment: I only now see that the `IdentityFile` line is using a relative path. You seem to be under the impression that this path is relative to the configuration file itself. I am not sure this is the case. Is there any documentation on this? (The man page on ssh_config(5) does not mention this in the section on `IdentityFile`.) What happens when you give an absolute path here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your listed hostname is correct? I would assume it's github.com. [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) does not list ssh.github.com.

Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797), using `IdentitiesOnly yes` is recommended, though this is most likely not the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes github recommends using ssh.github.com over port 443. https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port#enabling-ssh-connections-over-https